# Getting net.schmizz.sshj.xfer.scp.SCPException: EOF while expecting response to protocol message. while uploading file from linux to windows

Tags: windows, file-transfer, scp

I am using net.schmizz.sshj.xfer.scp.SCPFileTransfer class to upload file from local to remote server. It is failing with following error:

> net.schmizz.sshj.xfer.scp.SCPException: EOF while expecting response
>   to protocol message. Additional info: `bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching 
>   bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

This issue I am facing only when remote machine is Windows. For  Linux machine it is successfully uploading.
I have tried following steps in my code.
1. Download a file from remote machine to local
2. Upload same file again back to remote.

It is failing in step 2.

```
@Override
public boolean upload(String localLocation, String remoteLocation) throws SSHClientException {
    this.ensureConnected();
    SCPFileTransfer scp = this.sshj.newSCPFileTransfer();
    try {
        scp.upload(localLocation, remoteLocation);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Failed to copy file {} from local path at {} to remote location {} at {}" + remoteLocation,
                hostname, localLocation, e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any leads will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You know that Windows and Linux handle file formats differently?
`CR LF` is used in Windows while Linux only used `LF`. I would check how the files are encoded and how SCP handles the file format.
Have you also checked that the remote server accepts the file?

Comment: I have cygwin installed in my windows machine and passed the path as per cygdrive only. The path looks like  "/cygdrive/c/temp file/"

Comment: The error message suggests that the command being passed to the remote system (to invoke scp) is malformed. It has mismatched quoting or similar. Does your `remoteLocation` have any quote characters in it, or any other non-alphanumeric characters that might be special to the shell on the remote system?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
The remote file path that I have used looks like :
'/cygdrive/c/Program Files/XXX/'
The issue is "'" in the path. Removal of "'" from the path results successful upload of the file.

Thanks to all who gave me leads.

Thanks,
Shruti